# CSS or jQuery: text in two different colors in <select> dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I'd like to have the text in the `<option>` elements of a `<select>` menu displaying in two different colours, like so:

[image: Dropdown mockup]

I've been searching around for something definitive and mainly finding one or two *really old* threads indicating that it can't be done.

I appreciate that a CSS-only solution might be out of the question, and I'm already using [jQuery customSelect](https://github.com/adamcoulombe/jquery.customSelect) to style the dropdown, so using jQuery is definitely on the table; however this particular plugin only seems to affect/replace the selected top-level element and not the dropdown items.

If anyone has any suggestions or solutions - the lighter the better - that would be great.

Comment: How about two spans with seperated ids/classes?

Comment: @JoakimM As @Jon mentions below, the contents of `<option>` elements can't be styled with markup. Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/P7b5g/ - if you inspect a dropdown element with something like Firebug, you'll see that all the `<span>` tags are dropped.

Comment: Heard! :) Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this unless you completely replace the `<select>` element with a fully custom menu implementation. The spec [defines](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-option-element) that the content model of each option is [Text](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#text-content), which does not allow for the HTML elements that you would need to implement the colors. jQuery can't help you there because there is no wiggle room whatsoever.

If you are willing to consider a custom implementation then [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) is an excellent choice.

Comment: It is as I suspected - thanks for confirming this. I shall take a look at select2. My only concern is it might be a little heavy-handed (so many options!), but I'll give it a go and, if I find an alternative, I'll add a reference here.

Answer (score 0):

Can you write some code in a page like:

```
<option>Gamma <span>Delta</span></option>
```

Then you write next code in css stylesheet:

```
option span{
color:green;font-weight:bold;
}
```

Christian

Comment: Nope - as mentioned above, elements inside `<option>` tags are effectively ignored, as its contents are rendered purely as Text DOM elements. For reference: http://jsfiddle.net/P7b5g/1/